# Why do permissions change randomly when mounting via 9p method?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, virtio

The mounting is working perfectly fine. I mount the external share by using fstab with the following config:

```
data        /home/data            9p         trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L,_netdev,rw,uid=33,gid=33,dmask=007,fmask=007 0 0
```

The problem is every now and then the permission is changing and even though it should change www-data as owner with permission after reboot it certainly does not. I think this permission error is either the mounting is directet to a special user other then www-data or its when the hostsystem of the vm is accessing the folder or doing some kind of background job. Does somebody know how to fix this? I am using it to store my Nextcloud data and thats especially bad cause the nextcloud is randomly going into maintenance mode cause of the changed permissions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.